# SQL Performance compare IN to COUNT

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I am thinking about performance over all and came to the question how the fastest way to get rows from a table for that matter:

```
SELECT *
FROM table a
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT id FROM table b)
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM table a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table b WHERE b.id = a.id)>0
```

Running the profiler on my dev machine don't make a big difference, but I don't have huge data tables to compare that issue.

So it would be cool if someone can say which way is better and why.
I read once that `IN` split the values in many `OR` like `IN (1,2,3,4)` will be `1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4` but I am not sure if this is in general and the same if I query a sub select. In this case I would guess that the COUNT will be faster...

Comment: `WHERE` clause in the second query is invalid. There is no boolean expression in it

Comment: Missed the `>0` by typing it here, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Try to use EXISTS: `SELECT * FROM dbo.table a WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.table b WHERE b.id = a.id)`

Comment: Agree, `EXISTS` is preferrable

Comment: @Devart Good hint, will check this as well. But can anyone make a statement in general that this is faster "because..." or is this "just" best practice?

Comment: @YvesR, please give me a several minutes :)

Comment: `IN` and `EXISTS` will give the same plan. The `COUNT` one **may** do but it isn't always the case. See [comments here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see results on real DB (table with 100.000 records).

```
1. EXISTS - 803ms
2. COUNT - 814ms
3. IN - 870ms
```

[image: Profiler]

Comment: All of them have exactly the same number of logical reads so I wouldn't read much into the results from a single test. I would fully expect the execution plan for `EXISTS` and `IN` to be identical. The difference in perf could just be as the slower one was run first and brought data into the cache that benefited the later queries.

Comment: @Martin Smith, I used a local SQL server and reload it on every query execution. Possibly you're right. And thanks for you comment.

Comment: @Devart - Definitely you would need to do many performance tests before reaching any conclusion that one form is better than another when the timings are this close.

Comment: When I use `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;`, I get the similar results.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to obtain a COUNT when you need to determine if something EXISTS. COUNT should be used when you need to determine a quantity. COUNT will have to read all rows (either in the table or an index) to determine if they qualify, whereas EXISTS can stop processing as soon as it finds the first occurrence. Answer #1 supports this.